# Error getting stack gwelb from gateway to Cloud Integration Gateway using standard connector in Bluemix

Tags: cloud, integration, ibm-cloud

I was working with the Cloud Integration Gateway using the standard connector.  Setup was easy, except I tried installing the client on several systems and was getting the same error:

> 2016-01-20 19:47:21 SEVERE Exception while connecting to gateway. Exception is Error getting stack gwelb from gateway com.approuter.agent.client.util.ConnectionException: Error getting stack gwelb f
>   rom gateway at com.approuter.agent.client.ClientRegistrationUtil.getStackGatewayElb(ClientRegistrationUtil.java:260)

I finally watched the video and discovered the problem.  In the client settings, the gateway was set to gateway.castiron.com.  The DNS was resolving to 208.43.117.179 - in the video, the IP was hardcoded to 208.43.117.164.

When I hardcoded the IP address to 208.43.117.164, the client connected without any errors and came up immediately in Bluemix.

Sharing this here because I am hoping to save someone else the several days of troubleshooting.

Comment: Can you restructure this post into a question and answer please? Otherwise, it is likely to be flagged. Consider posting the first sentence and the error message with a question at the end. Then, move the rest of the information to the answer. You can answer your own question! Also, provide a link to the referenced video. SO wants technical questions and then answers. We don't want this question to look unanswered. Thanks!